# How to delete multiple tweets through Twitter API with a single transaction?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I am building a Twitter application that allow you to select multiple tweets and delete them. 
But is there any way to delete multiple tweets with a single transaction? the only way "I know" to delete tweets is by sending the tweet ID to destroy as shown the this link. http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/destroy/:id

Please if you know any other way tell me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you have to pass in the tweet id one at a time.